# Add an URI handler to xdg-open

Tags: linux

I want to associate Spotify URIs with my bash script that runs spotify, however, I don't know how to make xdg-open open spotify: URIs with that bash script.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xdg-open` uses `kfmclient`, `gnome-open` or `exo-open`, so you should configure the program that is used in your case.

Comment: thanks, I looked up uri adding for gnome-open and found this: http://people.w3.org/~dom/archives/2005/09/integrating-a-new-uris-scheme-handler-to-gnome-and-firefox/